# Change cart.total_price in Shopify - Once Checkout is pressed

Tags: ajax, shopify, cart

Objective: Give a discount to my clients when they buy 2 , 3 or + 4 products. I have successfully modified the cart to show a discount line and a modified total cart price.

The issue is that when the client pressed Checkout or Paypal the total price shown is the original one , not the modified for me in cart.liquid.

I have been looking around for a solution but found nothing clear enough. As far as I could read Ajax is required.

Could anyone help me? I am new to Ajax so please do not leave anything out in the explanation.

[image: Example]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have read up on using Shopify first. You cannot modify prices as you wish. There is no API possibility to do so. If you want to offer discounts you will have to follow the same patterns as every other Shopify merchant that has come before you. Typically, you can monitor the contents of a cart, and if you believe it to be enough to merit a discount, you can expose a discount code for the customer. It is not foolproof to monkey business, but it does work for most.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your answer. I am doing what you comment, I display a coupon & total price on the cart page, based on the number of products in it. And when my client goes to CheckOut he must type in the coupon himself to get the discount. But I am not happy with it, I believe there is a way to modify the cart total price through hidden variants and so. :(

Comment: Sure. There are some really bad patterns out there. Go for it. I get 10 calls a week from disgruntled merchants trying the Apps that try and fool the system. When you try and fake it, your inventory goes to hell, your accountant hates you and you'll love the mysteries you encounter in your quest for fire.